# Rails 3 Processing by */*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have noticed that in **`Rails 3.2.2`**, all actions are being processed with **`*/*`** format. So the question is: what means **`*/*`** ? And why it is called by default (every time) ?

Because there are two processings for one action:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-07 22:50:22 +0200
Processing by MainController#index as HTML

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-07 22:50:22 +0200
Processing by MainController#index as */*
```

I have tried to set:

```
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts)
  end
```

But the same problem still exists.

---

Just created project based on **`Rails 3.2.6`**. Tested with `Thin 1.4.1` and `Webrick`. Same issue:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop

Started GET "/mains" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-09 10:53:55 +0200
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by MainsController#index as HTML
  Main Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `mains`.* FROM `mains` 
  Rendered mains/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 51.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/mains" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-09 10:53:55 +0200
Processing by MainsController#index as */*
  Main Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `mains`.* FROM `mains` 
  Rendered mains/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: That just means anything/anything ie localhost/users/index, localhost/posts/index, etc. You could just setup your root route and your controller routes

Comment: Yes, it looks like so, but `root_path` is set already. I just don't understand why it is being called on every action?

Comment: I've noticed that Internet Explorer likes to do this if you hit Refresh.

Comment: Unfortunately same for refresh or simple process and it is Google Chrome.