# How can the same request by interpreted as JSON and as */* in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

**note:** the gist of the question is in the first update below

I'm maintaing a rails project and I noticed that if I do a `GET "/request/past_list"` I'm routed to `RequestController#show`

in `routes.rb` I got:

```
get '/request/past_list', to: 'request#past_list'
get '/request/:id', to: 'request#show'
```

and running `rake routes` I get (predictably):

```
request_past_list GET     /request/past_list(.:format)     request#past_list
                  GET     /request/:id(.:format)           request#show
```

So i'm wondering why is rails thinking that my `past_list` string in the url is actually an `:id`?

for now this is the workaround I implemented:

```
def show
  if ((params[:id]).is_a? String and (params[:id].eql? "past_list"))
    past_list  
  else
    ..
```

but i'm already having trouble sleeping at night because of it.. i'm hoping to know what's really going on to rest my conscience

p.s. this is what the network request looks like on chrome dev tools, just in case if there is some detail that may raise a red flag:

[image]

**update:** i noticed a difference between how the request is interpreted in my current code:

```
Started GET "/request/past_list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-13 15:41:14 +0200
Processing by RequestController#show as JSON
```

and the old working one i dug up from git history:

```
Started GET "/request/past_list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-13 15:43:40 +0200
Processing by RequestController#past_list as */*
```

the thing is the old working code has the exact same routes.rb file.. no changes there!

so i guess it's a difference between interpreting the request as `JSON` and as `*/*`..

**second update:**
here are two questions related to this `*/*` business:
[When do Rails controllers render as JS, HTML, or 'q'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977462/when-do-rails-controllers-render-as-js-html-or-q)
and 
[Rails 3 Processing by */*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378626/rails-3-processing-by?rq=1)

Comment: can you provide the relevant output of `rake routes`?

Comment: @xlembouras i already did

Comment: change `past_list` to `:past_list` in your `routes.rb` then you should be getting `params[:past_list]` or you write a redirection in your `show` action when the `params[:id] == past_list`

Comment: Does it happen even when you use double quotes?

Comment: @Bala double quotes didn't work, same result (see my update though)

Comment: @bjhaid i'm afraid that work around isn't much better than mine.. look at my update though

Answer (score 0):

it turns out I had this in my routes.rb file:

```
get '/request/:id', to: 'request#show', :defaults => {:format => :json}
```

so i simply deleted it.

To give you guys a take away from this discussion.. the trick was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338145/766570) git command:

```
$ git diff $things_were_working_commit..$things_weren't_working_commit -- routes.rb
```

after that it was all obvious!